# Fetching Open Graph Metadata with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, express, facebook-opengraph, create-react-app

#### The problem

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) with Firebase and it's been a dream but I've hit a roadbloack. I'd like to incorporate into my app fetching Open Graph metadata from a user supplied URL but as we know, this is prevented when done in the browser.

This example of [Open Graph Metadata With Node](http://blog.stephenwyattbush.com/2011/06/27/scraping-open-graph-metadata-with-node) is very close to what I'm trying to do.

#### What I've tried

I've reviewed the readme file, specifically [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

I've searched the issues here and on the create-react-app Github repo (open and closed) for something relevant. A few results have come back on CORS and similar but still quite a few gaps in how to incorporate something to accomplish this.

I've read tuts suggesting that I should use Express but I'm not sure how that can be incorporated with create-react-app and webpack (not to mention how this would work in production).

I think I'm just not quite putting all the pieces together to accomplish this and would appreciate guidance if someone has the time.

The package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.7",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-avatar": "^2.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just paying it forward here with how I solved this for myself.

First, I created a new project only for fetching Open Graph data. It has two main files; `package.json` and `server.js`.

I decided to go with the [open-graph-scraper](https://github.com/jshemas/openGraphScraper) module because it was recommend by a few online authorities and seems like it has some pretty good fallbacks when OG isn't available on a site.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Extract Open Graph info.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "open-graph-scraper": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "tape": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/your-repo"
  }
}
```

For the server, I setup my route as just the parent route `/` (because that's really only what it was being used for) and used the open graph **scraper** module to return site data.

`server.js`

```
var ogs = require('open-graph-scraper');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.query['url']){

    var siteUrl = req.query['url'];
    var options = {
      'url': siteUrl,
      'headers': {
        'accept-language': 'en'
      },
      'timeout': 4000
    };

    ogs(options, function (err, results, response) {
      if(results.err){
        res.json(results.err);
      } else {
        res.json(results);
        res.end();
      }
    });

  }
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log("Express server listening on port %d", port);
```

Last, I [deployed to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). From here, you can query the site data using something like [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) in your ReactJS project.

By sending a request to the URL with the following structure, you'll receive a response from the OG scraper with site info in JSON format. An example request:

http://example.heroku.com?url=http://github.com

It will return the Open Graph info for github.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is down voted but if someone has feedback on how I've done it here then I can learn how to improve my implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal solution here would be to set up an API and proxy the request.

1. User makes request to fetch Open Graph data that resides on a third party server
2. The request gets passed to your API
3. Your API makes the request
4. Your API sends the data back to the browser in JSON format

The API and your ReactJS application are separate entities. Do not treat them the same. ReactJS will make requests to your API, but that's all it will do.

I use PHP (and the Slim framework) for my APIs, but you can use whatever language you feel most comfortable with. Express is a good option if you're comfortable using it.

Depending on the size of your application in production you could have your ReactJS application and API on the same server. Or, you could have your ReactJS application on a CDN server, and the API on another. For an application that's expected to get a lot of traffic I go with the second option and load balance the API and CDN.

If you want to go with Express, take a look at their docs. Spend some time playing with it and get a feel for how things work.

Express isn't too difficult, and it's not your only option. I hear good things about [Feathers](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/about/features.html) although have not used it myself.

Here's a list of some libraries/frameworks to check out:

- [Hapi.js](https://hapijs.com/)
- [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/)
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)
- [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/)
- [Mean.js](http://meanjs.org/)
- [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/)
- [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com/)
- [Loopback](https://loopback.io/)

Comment: I think the missing piece for me was not thinking about this in terms of 2 separate projects: an API for returning OG data & the ReactJS app itself. Instead I was assuming I could just mash this both together and be on my way. But I can see how it could make things a lot easier for me in the short term and probably also down the road if I split this off into two projects.

Comment: Just a bit of Googling landed me on this Open Graph API: https://www.opengraph.io/ Any experience with that @BigHunterUK? Might be a way for me to keep working on the main app itself without getting bogged down with building my own API right away.

Comment: I don't have any experience with that service. And yes it's always better to keep things separate. In the long run it pays off and makes it easy to horizontally scale your application. You could setup a server that does the same as opengraph.io and not have to pay fees to use the service :)

Comment: The more I'm looking at all the different NPM packages already out there for open graph the more I'm seeing how easy it would be to just roll with my own straight away. Cheers!